# IE7 visibility bug

Tags: html, css

I'm experiencing a visibility: hidden bug in IE7. My CSS is as follows:

```
.image {
float:left;
width:298px;
visibility:hidden;
*visibility: hidden;
}
```

Basically I want everything contained within the div to be hidden, but still occupy and reserve the space (so in this case display: none doesn't work). It works in all browsers except IE7, which seems to ignore the visibility line in the CSS.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you have `visibility:hidden` twice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using text-indent

```
.image {
float:left;
width:298px;

text-indent: -10000px;

}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/yQuAH/)

Answer (score 0):

Dipaks' answer is pretty much what I'd go for too. A slightly different alternative would be to use `left: -10000px;` See which works best cross-browser. If you have any problems with either, try adding `position: relative;` to this and `overflow: hidden;` to the parent element - I have a hunch (I don't have a copy of IE7 handy to check) that IE might cause the area to increase by 10000px, which will mess up your page widths.

Answer (score 0):

Add visibility: hidden to the image instead: http://jsfiddle.net/simply_simpy/n9qZ8/1/

`<img class="image" src="http://i.cdn.turner.com/cnn/.e/img/3.0/global/header/hdr-main.gif">​`

`.image {
float:left;
width:298px;
visibility:hidden;
*visibility: hidden;
}​`